# Removing duplicates from csv and rearranging the data into columns with JAVA

Tags: java, csv

I am looking for some help. I have an application at work that generates a csv with user information on it. I want to use Java and take the data, delete duplicate information, rearrange it, and create a spreadsheet, to make life easier. The csv is generated in the following format, but much larger:

```
21458952, a1234, Doe, John, technology, support staff, work phone, 555-555-5555

21458952, a1234, Doe, John, technology, support staff, work email, johndoe@whatever.net

21458952, a1234, Doe, John, technology, support staff, work pager, 555-555-5555

99946133, b9854, Paul, Jane, technology, administration, work phone, 444-444-4444

99946133, b9854, Paul, Jane, technology, administration, work email, janepaul@whatever.net

99946133, b9854, Paul, Jane, technology, administration, work pager, 444-444-4444

99946133, b9854, Paul, Jane, technology, administration, cell phone, 444-444-4444
```

I want to delete the duplicates and arrange the data in appropriate columns.

```
ID | PIN | Lname | Fname | Dept | team | work px | work email
```

I have been trying to build arrays with a BufferedReader to store the data, but I am running into difficulties dealing with duplicates and manipulating the data into a table.

This is the code I have so far

```
public class Sort {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     BufferedReader br = null;

     try{
            String line="";
            String csvSplitBy=(",");
            String outPut;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Jason/Desktop/test.txt"));    //location where the file is retreived 

            while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null){  //checks to see if the data is there
                   String[] id = line.split(csvSplitBy);

                   outPut = id[0] + "," + id[1] + "," + id[2] + "," + id[3] + "," + id[4] + "," + id[5] + "," + id[6] + "," + id[7]
                           + "," + id[8] + "," + id[9];//incomplete...using for test...


                 System.out.println(outPut);   //displays the contents of the .txt file
                   } //ends while statement 
             } //ends try

     catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println ("File not found!");
         } //ends catch
         finally{
                try{
                       if (br !=null)br.close();}
                catch(IOException ex){
                       ex.printStackTrace();
                } //ends try
         } //ends finally
   } //ends main method
```

} //ends class Sort

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please show the code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: You probably want to use a library to save yourself a lot of trouble.  Check out: [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) or [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

you should create a class to hold the data then create a List, then if the data isn't in the list , add it!